# How to apply conditional CSS class based on Json string response using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, json, angularjs

I want to apply css classes based on JSON response for example if response is "Low" i want background color green and apply radio-low css class and if response is "medium" i want to make background color yellow.How i can acieve this task using AngularJS.

HTML

```
    <form kendo-validator="ratingValidator" name="processRatingForm" novalidate ng-cloak
        ng-controller="EditProcessRatingCtrl" class="border-box-sizing grids-fonts">
        <p class="status">{{PrcsratingValidationMsg}}</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div>
                    <label class="control-label" for="processInherentRisk">Process
                        Inherent risk rating</label>
                </div>
                <div  id="processInhRisk"
                    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-model="processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey" class="radio-low" >{{processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div>
                    <label class="control-label" for="finalOutcomeInherentRiskRatingKey">Process
                        Inherent risk Business Final</label>
                </div>
                <div id="irrFinalOutcome"
                    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                    ng-model="processRating.finalOutcomeInherentRiskRatingKey" class="radio-medium">{{processRating.finalOutcomeInherentRiskRatingKey}}</div>
            </div>
</div
</form>
```

Comment: Have a look at [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: your title doesn't math the problem very well.. you should consider changing it

Comment: juz pass the value you getting from the json into ng-class. Assign css color value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class directive.

```
<div ng-class="{processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey === 'low': 'radio-low'}" >{{processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey}}</div>
```

Edit:

```
<div ng-class="{processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey === 'low': 'radio-low', processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey === 'high': 'radio-high'}" >{{processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey}}</div>
```

Comment: How about if this field response is high ?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to test the output and put the result in a `$scope` variable, then use that `$scope` variable in an `ng-class` declaration.

**HTML**

```
<div id="processInhRisk" ... ng-class="{processRating.isMedium: medium}">{{processRating.finalOutcomeInherentRiskRatingKey}}</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.processRating.isMedium = processRating.finalOutcomeInherentRiskRatingKey == 'medium';
```

**CSS**

```
.medium { background-color: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value to class(low,high) and mention the color in css.

HTML

```
<div id="processInhRisk" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-model="processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey" ng-class="{{processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey" >{{processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey}}</div>
```

css

```
.low{
color: bla bla bla
}
.high{
color: bla bla bla
}
```

Make sure you are getting the color code correctly in json